# Bash Word generating loop

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a word loop that generates a 5 letter word and tests is against a test then if it is incorrect generates the next word. However currently it is generating all 53,200 words at once, I only want "myword" to be 1 word at at time

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
for n in $(seq 0 54000)
do
    IFS=$''
    hash="hash"
    myword=$(echo {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z} |  awk '{print $1}')
    test=$(echo -n "$myword" | awk '{print $1}')
    if [ "$test" == "$hash" ]
    then
        echo "!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! The password is     $test1   !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"
        break
    else
        echo "Password   $myword  is incorrect"
        echo "$test"
    fi
done
```

this is within a loop.

Comment: Show the entire loop

Comment: There you go.. :)

Comment: Similar question on Unix&Linux : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243802/combination-generator-with-memory-and-resource-management

Comment: Don't use *either* `seq` or `{...}` for such a large list; use `for ((i=0;i<=54000;i++)); do`.

Comment: That thread doesn't have a solution that works for me

Comment: I need the words to output like this:
aaaaa  //New Line//
aaaab  //New Line//
aaaab //New Line//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't actually using either `i` or `n` here; what you really want to iterate over are the possible 5-letter combinations. This isn't really recommended, since it will take a very long time to generate the full list to generate before you can begin the iteration:

```
hash="hash"
for myword in {a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}{a..z}; do
    test=$(echo -n "$myword" |  awk '{print $1}')
    if [[ $test = $hash ]]; then
        break
    else
        ...
    fi
done
```

It would be better to break up the iteration into more discrete chunks; it won't be any faster overall, but you can at least start the actual computation without first generating all 11,881,376 possibilities in memory.

```
for a in {a..z}; do
  for b in {a..z}; do
    for c in {a..z}; do
      for d in {a..z}; do
        for e in {a..z}; do
            myword="$a$b$c$d$e"
            test1=...
            if [[ ... ]]; then
              break 5
            fi
        done
      done
    done
  done
done
```

But the best idea would be to do this in a language designed for general data processing, not `bash`. In particular, a language with a library for computing SHA-256 checksums, rather than forking a new program for each password.

Comment: Thanks mate your the best :)

Comment: How do I get this to stop?

Comment: The script wont stop with break, or exit 1

Comment: I updated the nested example so that the it will break out of all the loops when a successful match is found.